# Unknown password hashing algorithm. PASSWORD_HASHERS setting - using factory boy

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, factory-boy

If I create sample User account for test I have this error:

> Unknown password hashing algorithm 'password1'. Did you specify it in
> the PASSWORD_HASHERS setting?

```
class ExampleTest(TestCase):
    def test_sample_data(self):
        for i in range(0,1):
            user = content.factories.UserFactory.create()
```

factories.py:

```
class UserFactory(factory.Factory):
    FACTORY_FOR = User

    username = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'User' + n)
    email = 'mail@gmail.com'
    password = 'password1'
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE.** It's described in [documentation](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html?highlight=password#postgenerationmethodcall), you should use `factory.PostGenerationMethodCall`:

```
class UserFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    username = 'user'
    password = factory.PostGenerationMethodCall('set_password',
                                                'defaultpassword')
```

**OLD ANSWER**.
Actually, this is described in [factory-boy documentation](https://github.com/dnerdy/factory_boy#customizing-creation):

```
class UserFactory(factory.Factory):
    @classmethod
    def _prepare(cls, create, **kwargs):
        password = kwargs.pop('password', None)
        user = super(UserFactory, cls)._prepare(create, **kwargs)
        if password:
            user.set_password(password)
            if create:
                user.save()
        return user
```

Better use this solution, so you can correctly use `UserFactory.build()`, `UserFactory.create()` and `UserFactory.attributes()` (later will return unhashed password)

Comment: ya, has moved to: https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html?highlight=password#postgenerationmethodcall

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserFactory(factory.Factory):
    FACTORY_FOR = User

    username = 'user'
    password = factory.PostGenerationMethodCall('set_password',
                                            'defaultpassword')
```

See docs here https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/v1.3.0/reference.html#postgenerationmethodcall

Answer (score 0):

```py
user = content.factories.UserFactory.create()
user.set_password('yourpassword')
user.save()
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15116483/3) to the question [Unknown password hashing algorithm. PASSWORD_HASHERS setting - using factory boy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15116483/unknown-password-hashing-algorithm-password-hashers-setting-using-factory-boy) by the OP [edekmax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2108300/edekmax) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>